# Chrome File Link Big Length - Tab Crashes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, download, jszip

I am using JSZip to create zip files in my HTML page. Once the zip files are created, I put these files for download using the following mechanism

```
document.getElementById(elementId).href = "data:application/zip;base64,"+content;
```

This works fine for normal situations. However, sometimes the zip files are longer than 2 MB and hence the url becomes of length greater than 2097152 characters. When I click on this link, the tab crashes. From this [link](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/5), I have found that

> The current URL length limit in chrome is 2097152 characters

I wanted to know what are the possible ways to solve this issue without splitting the zip file. Is there a different way to present the file for download?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `saveAs` in recent browsers (or the [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) polyfill). From http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/write_zip.html :

```
var blob = zip.generate({type:"blob"});
saveAs(blob, "hello.zip");
```

Comment: Thanks David. I will try this out but had a question. Does saveAs open a popup like location.href? Because I do not want popup. Instead, I want to store the download link in a element which the user can later click to download. The reason for this is that there are multiple zip files generated during 1 run and I would not want to have popup asking to save for each file. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you will get the download popup as soon as you call `saveAs`. You can use a blob url to get the behavior you want (be sure to test on IE 10/11, I had issue with them last time I tried). An other solution is to store the generated zip and trigger the `saveAs` call when the user click on a link.

Comment: How would I store the zip and trigger saveAs on click? Where would the blob be stored for that period?